# What Linux Distribution is elementary OS based on?

Tags: release-freya, system

I am a regular user of Ubuntu, also used Arch in VM. I recently installed elementary OS. I like to use `commands` from terminal for installation or to launch an application.

My question is: Which distribution is elementary OS based on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is based on Ubuntu.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS)  See the first sentence of the Wikipedia page.  So all your regular commands should work well with it.